# MULTI: bad source address from client - Router all traffics over openvpn

Tags: networking, openvpn

I run openvpn client in my laptop, and run openvpn server at remote server (ec2 or aliyun). I want all traffics go over openvpn server. When connection is setup between laptop and openvpn server, I could not visit any internet with message at server side:

```
client/131.202.160.31:59288 MULTI: bad source address from client [131.202.160.31], packet dropped
```

131.202.160.31 is my laptop address. The route information at the server is:

```
root@iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z:~# ip route  show
default via 172.16.63.253 dev eth0 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
172.16.48.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.62.150 
root@iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:0e:1c:43  
          inet addr:172.16.62.150  Bcast:172.16.63.255  Mask:255.255.240.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

Some related pages are [Redirect all traffic via openvpn](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect), and [AskUbuntu bad source address](https://serverfault.com/questions/646130/multi-bad-source-address-from-client-any-one-off-solutions), and [Explaination](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/317-qmulti-bad-source-address-from-client--packet-droppedq-or-qget-inst-by-virt-failedq.html).

The explanation is much clear, but i am still very confused. 
1) The error shows that openvpn server does not know how to forward for a package, and it is because there are a subnet work behind the VPN client. In my case, it is only a single laptop client that runs openvpn client.

2) I am not familiar with network. Can anyone provide a sample for ccd configuration at server.conf(e.g., masks, iroute)? It looks like that this configuration will include my laptop's addresses. In my case, the my laptop address is dynamic, and it would frequently be moved around.

---

The server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
verb 5
;mute 20
push "redirect-gateway def1" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1" #The result is the same even I use the openDNS
```

and

```
root@iZbp15fejv9adv7o3izfm1Z:/etc/openvpn#  iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
```

I add following instructions at the end of /etc/rc.local

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

service dnsmasq restart
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you post your openvpn server configuration file? Also output of  iptables -L -t nat

Comment: @tomodachi, see my update..